# Looking for a more elegant way to get a 2D numpy array of azimuthal angles in cylinder coordinates

Tags: python, math, numpy

The title says it all. I am looking for a way to write the calculation of azimuthal angles in a 2D array more elegant. It has to do with the fact, that the arcus functions are only defined on a range from 0 to pi or -pi/2 to pi/2. Any Ideas?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Setup
x = np.linspace(-10, 10, 200)
y = np.linspace(-10, 10, 200)
x, y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
r = (x**2+y**2)**0.5

#get array of azimuthal angles
phi = np.arctan(y/x)
phi = np.where(np.less_equal(x, 0), phi+np.pi, phi)
phi = np.where(np.logical_and(np.greater_equal(x, 0), np.less_equal(y, 0)), phi+2*np.pi, phi)

#Test the calculation
# make a pizza with one slice missing
z = np.where(np.logical_and(np.less_equal(r, 5), np.less_equal(phi, 2*np.pi*(1-1/12)), np.less_equal(0, phi)), 1, 0)

#plot it
plt.imshow(z, extent=[-10, 10, -10, 10], origin="Upper")
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

**EDIT:**
As you guys have pointed out, I could use `arctan2`-Function for this job, however the discontinuous section with this function is at +/- pi and not at 0/2pi as I need it to be.

I could define `phi` using this function as:

```
phi = np.arctan2(y, x)+2*np.pi*(np.sign(-y)+np.abs(np.sign(-y)))/2
```

However that is not very pretty either...

**EDIT 2: Solution**

As @MvG pointed out, the following definitions do exactly what I need.

```
phi = np.pi + np.arctan2(-y, -x)
```

or

```
phi = np.pi - np.arctan2(y, -x)
```

Comment: @throwaway Do you know of `np.arctan2`?

Comment: As I answered to MvG this does not really what I want, please check out the comment there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The common way in most programming languages to turn a pair of coordinates into an angle is using a function conventionally called [`atan2`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2). As [gboffi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2749397/gboffi) already mentioned in a comment, the numpy equivalent is called [`numpy.arctan2`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arctan2.html). And while you are at it, you might want to use [`numpy.hypot`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.hypot.html) to compute `r`.

Since you indicate in both a comment and an edit of your question that you care particularly about the [0,2π] range, let's look at that. There are essentially two ways how you can map the result of `atan2`, which is in the range [-π,π] to the range you desire: Take π and either add or subtract the result from atan2. It doesn't make much of a difference which of these you choose. If you add, then you want to turn the input to `atan2` by 180°, which means negating both coordinates. You end up with

```
phi = np.pi + np.arctan2(-y, -x)
```

If you subtract, then you can take the above as a starting point but flip the sign of the `y` coordinate to flip the entry. The result in this case would be

```
phi = np.pi - np.arctan2(y, -x)
```

As I said, both should lead to the same result. The second might perhaps be a bit faster since it requires one operation less. The first might be easier to think about and therefore easier to maintain. Apparently there *is* a difference for the `y=0` case, where the first line results in 2π but the second results in 0. I'm a bit surprised by this, because I'd have expected the distinction between `+0` and `-0` to make a difference for `atan2`, thus leading to the same result in the end.

Comment: That is not really what I need though. An array made with arctan2 would go from positiv x-Axis counter clockwise to pi and then would suddenly turn negativ and count down to zero. What I need is a continuous angle distribution from 0 to 2*pi, counter clockwise.

Comment: @throwaway17434: Improved my post to cater for your range requirements.

Comment: Thank you very much for this! Btw... I looked at the documentary of `numpy.hypot`, but it says it is equivalent to what I used "element-wise", and I just did a calculation time check with the `time` module. `hypot` takes about 30% longer to calculate. Why exactly did you suggest to use this function?

Comment: @throwaway17434: For once, `hypot` it is easier to read. But in addition to this, I know from the equivalent Java function [`Math.hypot`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#hypot-double-double-) that according to it's documentation it is more robust against intermediate overflow, i.e. cases where the squares would overflow even though the final value is still in range. Decide for yourself if this is an issue for you, and if so, whether numpy offers comparable benefits without stating them in the docs.